# SQL query for finding how many books have more than 20 reviews

Tags: sql, count

I am new to SQL queries and I am having trouble to the following problem. We have a table of book reviews (`review_id, book_id,...`) and a table `review_good_bad` (`review_id, IsGood`) that shows if the review is good or not.

`Review_id` of the table `review_good_bad` is a foreign key and `IsGood` is a boolean. I have to find how many books have at least 20 reviews.

I have tried this:

```
Select count(dinstict r.book_id)
From reviews r, review_good_bad rgb
Where r.review_id = rgb.review_id
Group by r.book_id
Having count (rgb.IsGood) >= 20
```

However it is not what I am asking for. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @PadK . . . Your data structure doesn't really make sense.  Why not just store `isgood` in the `reviews` table?

Comment: You really don't need join unless you want to find books with good reviews > 20.

Comment: @Gordon Linnof. I did not create the tables dude. My professor did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't aggregate on the column that you use in the GROUP BY clause.
Use your query as a subquery and aggregate on that:

```
select count(*)
from (
  select r.book_id
  from reviews r inner join review_good_bad rgb
  on r.review_id = rgb.review_id
  group by r.book_id
  having count(rgb.IsGood) >= 20
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want good reviews which your CODE suggests you want:

```
select count(*)
from (select book_id
      from reviews r
           review_good_bad rgb
           using (book_id)
      where rgb.IsGood
      group by book_id
     ) r;
```

Doing unnecessary comparisons -- such as your code does with `isGood` -- is misleading at best and can lead to poor performance.  Filtering before aggregation usually improves performance.

Note that your data structure doesn't really make sense.  You should just store `IsGood` in the `reviews` table.

This also replaces your archaic syntax with proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  This also allows niceties such as the `using` clause.

If you don't need the `IsGood` then it should not be reference in the query.  And neither should the table it is in.  Just use:

```
select count(*)
from (select r.book_id
      from reviews r
      group by book_id
      having count(*) >= 20
     ) r;
```

This should be the simplest answer to your question (if not about good reviews).

Comment: *I have to find how many books have at least 20 reviews* The question is not about books having good reviews.

Comment: @forpas . . . You are right that that is based on the CODE and not the question per se.  I've edited the answer to have a superior solution if that is not the case.

Comment: This would work only if the relation between reviews and review_good_bad is 1:1 which I don't believe is the case.

Comment: @forpas . . . I strongly disagree.  The question is about counting *reviews*.  That is presumably rows in the `reviews` table.  Any use of the other table would (in a non 1:1 scenario) affect the count.  The join would be just wrong in that case.

Comment: If this is the case then the whole table review_good_bad is redundand. The column IsGood could exist inside reviews and this would be the only table.